# I want to make a mysql trigger that combines three tables is it possible

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

This is what I want to change the value 2 of table 2 and to automatically update the table1 value1 in another table.

```
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER update_count2 AFTER update ON table2.value2
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 update table1.value1
 join table2.value2 on foreignkeyoftable1 = primaryKeyftable2
 join table3.value3 on primarykeyoftable3= foreignkeyoftable2
 set table1.value1 = value2 * value3;
 END $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this kind of trigger, and update query.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_count AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
update table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
join table3 t3 on t1.id = t3.id
set t1.updateColumn = t2.value * t3.value
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: the t1.id is it the foreign key ? or is it the field that I am multiplying?

Comment: I try to insert by hand and the database doesn't allow me to do the change the trigger was succesfully created though.

Comment: You should ask a question with whatever you have tried with database structure. Also use sqlfiddle.com which is very useful for us to help you.

Comment: Now It allows me to make changes but the field that I want is not affected I would like to say that there are three tables.table1 is connected with table2 and table 2 with table 3 .Table 1 and 3 are not connected with foreign key.

Comment: it does not do the multiplying .

Comment: please update your question or ask a new question with sample database table structure.